# Prepend header to file without changing the file

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting, enscript

### Background

The [`enscript`](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) command can apply syntax highlighting to various types of source files, including SQL statements, shell scripts, PHP code, HTML files, and more. I am using `enscript` to generate 300dpi images of source code for a technical manual to:

- Generate content for the book based on actual source code.
- Distribute the source code along with the book, without any modification.
- Run and test the scripts while writing the book.

### Problem

The following shell script performs the conversion almost as desired:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRNAME=$(dirname $1)
FILENAME=$(basename $1)

# Remove the extension from the filename.
BASENAME=${FILENAME%%.*}
FILETYPE=${FILENAME##*.}

LIGHTGRAY="#f3f3f3"

enscript --escapes --color -f Courier10 -X ps -B -1 --highlight=$FILETYPE \
  $2 -h -o - $1 | \
  gs -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dNOPAUSE -r300 \
  -sOutputFile=$BASENAME.png -dBackgroundColor=16$LIGHTGRAY > /dev/null && \
  convert -trim $BASENAME.png $BASENAME-trimmed.png && \
  mv $BASENAME-trimmed.png $BASENAME.png
```

The problem is that the background is not a light gray colour. According to the `enscript` man page, the `--escapes` (`-e`) option indicates that the file (i.e., `$1`) has `enscript`-specific control sequences embedded within it.

Adding the control sequences means having to duplicate code, which defeats the purpose of having a single source.

### Solution

The `enscript` documentation implies that it should be possible to concatenate two files together (the target and a "header") before running the script, to create a third file:

```
^@shade{0.85}                  -- header line
#!/bin/bash                    -- start of source file
```

Then delete the third file once the command completes.

### Questions

**Q.1.** What is a more efficient way to pipe the control sequences *and* the source file to the `enscript` program without using a third file?

**Q.2.** What other options are available to automate syntax highlighting for a book, while honouring the single source requirements I have described? (For example, write the book in LyX and use LaTeX commands for import and syntax highlighting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1** You can use braces '`{}`' to do I/O redirection:

```
{ echo "^@shade{0.85}"; cat $1; } |
enscript --color -f Courier10 -X ps -B -1 --highlight=$FILETYPE $2 -h -o - |
gs -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dNOPAUSE -r300 \
   -sOutputFile=$BASENAME.png -dBackgroundColor=16$LIGHTGRAY > /dev/null &&
convert -trim $BASENAME.png $BASENAME-trimmed.png &&
mv $BASENAME-trimmed.png $BASENAME.png
```

This assumes that enscript reads its standard input when not given an explicit file name; if not, you may need to use an option (perhaps '`-i -`') or some more serious magic, possibly even 'process substitution' in bash.

You could also use parentheses to run a sub-shell:

```
(echo "^@shade{0.85}"; cat $1) | ...
```

Note that the semi-colon after `cat` is necessary with braces and not necessary with parentheses (and a space is necessary after the open brace) - such are the mysteries of shell scripting.

**Q2** I don't have any alternatives to offer.  When I produced a book (20 years ago now, using troff), I wrote a program to convert source into the the necessary markup, so that the book was produced from the source code, but by an automated process.

(Is 300 dpi sufficiently high resolution?)

#### Edit

To work-around the `enscript` program interpreting the escape sequence embedded in the conversion script itself:

```
{ cat ../../enscript-header.txt $1; } |
```

Comment: `cat` takes multiple files as arguments (that's what it's for after all): `{ cat ../../enscript-header.txt "$1"; } |`

Answer (score 1):

**Q2:** Use LaTeX with the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package.

Comment: It turns out that there's a bug with enscript. http://i.imgur.com/h2Hdx.png If you look carefully at the image, you can see lines drawn between the if/echo/exit/fi statements. I was trying to avoid LaTeX (because it is *so* time-consuming to make aesthetically beautiful books). The defaults are nearly typographically perfect, though.

Comment: I’m afraid that listings has the same problem when using a background color :-(

Comment: `convert $BASENAME.png -fuzz 20% -fill 'rgb(243,243,243)' -opaque white $BASENAME-filled.png` will remove the lines using `enscript` and ImageMagick.